# Different Taylor expansion justification

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

I found in the literature the following expansion in power series.

Given the regular function $A(k^2)$:
$$A(k^2)=A(k^2=0)+ \frac{dA}{dk}(k^2=0)k^2+A_c(k^2)k^2$$
with $A_c(k^2)$ that goes at least linearly to zero when $k \longrightarrow 0$

Notice that $A_c(k^2)$ is not evaluated in $k=0$.

I was used to consider the Taylor expansion as:
$$A(k^2)=A(k^2=0)+ \frac{dA}{dk}(k^2=0)k^2+ o(k^4)$$

> If the expression are equivalent how to see that.